# add click event for button in ListView empty view in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment, empty-list

I have problem regarding ListView in ListFragment.I want to show empty view in list, when list adapter dose not have a item.This empty view has button. so i need to add click event listener for that button in my ListFragment

my view is like following.

[image]

please help me on this.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

In order to have more complex layouts for the empty view of a ListFragment you need to override the onCreateView() method to load a [custom layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) with "android:list" and "android:empty" views. This will allow you to specifiy the complex empty view you desire, and inside that method you can access to the Button view to set the click listener.